# Facebook doesnt fetch meta tags from new pages

Tags: facebook, fetch, meta-tags

I have several webpages with facebook metatags. The problem is, that Facebook is starting recognize them only after I've used object's Debugger. How can I force Facebook to automatically resolve all my meta-tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

You can automaticlly send request like that:
curl -X POST \
     -F "id={object-url OR object-id}" \
     -F "scrape=true" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com"

to URL you want to scrape